# C-u leaves ghost characters at command prompt in xterm

Tags: bash, x11, xterm, readline

I am using bash (v3.2.25) on linux, through xterm, through exceed. When using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> the cursor is moved next to the bash character prompt (`$`) but the rest of the line remains and is not erased as expected.

Where is the issue, xterm or bash? How to resove that issue please?

Comment: What does `bind -p | grep '\C-u'` return?

Answer (score 1):

bash is meant to send the escape sequence that in the terminfo database is known as "el" (clear to the end of line).

So another possibility is that the terminfo database is not correct (or possibly that the wrong entry in the terminfo database is queried if `$TERM` is not set properly.

Does `tput el | cat -vt` give you something like `^[[K`? What's the value of `$TERM`?

For instance, I could obtain the same behavior as you describe by setting `$TERM` to `mterm` (where `el` is `^C`).

You could also run bash through `script` to see what escape sequence is actually sent by bash upon <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>

Comment: $ tput el | cat -vt 
^[[K

Comment: And : $echo $TERM
xterm

Comment: Does `printf 'abc\r\033[K\n'` output an empty line or abc?